¿Por qué no se lanza el evento submit al presionar un input submit?
Tengo el problema de que al hacer click en un input tipo submit, no puedo capturar el evento submit en el formulario con un event listener del evento submit. Al hacer click en ese botón solo me dice que complete los campos que tienen el atributo required, pero en mi formulario tengo inputs a los que no se les puede colocar el atributo required, como checkbox y range, por que tengo que validarlos mediante JavaScript. Para que  la validación automática de los inputs con el atributo required se incorpore con la validación de las etiquetas sin el atributo required, tuve que agregar un event listener del evento submit al formulario.


// Fragmento del código que controla que al estar seleccionado el botón de opción, aparezca el campo de texto
const botonOpcion7 = document.getElementById('opcion7');
const botonOpcion8 = document.getElementById('opcion8');
const labelOpcion8 = document.querySelector('.label8-input');
const opcion8Input = document.getElementById('opcion8-input');
const botonOpcion14 = document.getElementById('opcion14');
const botonOpcion15 = document.getElementById('opcion15');
const labelOpcion15 = document.querySelector('.label15-input');
const opcion15Input = document.getElementById('opcion15-input');
const brs = document.querySelectorAll('.br');
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
var btnEnviarFormulario = document.querySelector('.btn-enviar');

function seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton1() 
{
    if (botonOpcion7.checked == true)
    {
        labelOpcion8.style.display = 'none';
        opcion8Input.style.display = 'none';
        opcion8Input.required = false
        brs.forEach(br => {br.style.display = 'none'});
    }
    else if (botonOpcion8.checked == true)
    {
        labelOpcion8.style.display = 'block';
        opcion8Input.style.display = 'block';
        opcion8Input.required = true;
        brs.forEach(br => {br.style.display = 'block'});
    }
}

function seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton2()
{
    if (botonOpcion14.checked == true)
    {
        labelOpcion15.style.display = 'none';
        opcion15Input.style.display = 'none';
        opcion15Input.required = false;
        brs.forEach(br => {br.style.display = 'none'});
    }
    else if (botonOpcion15.checked == true)
    {
        labelOpcion15.style.display = 'block';
        opcion15Input.style.display = 'block';
        opcion15Input.required = true;
        brs.forEach(br => {br.style.display = 'block'});
    }
}
botonOpcion7.addEventListener('change', seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton1);
botonOpcion8.addEventListener('change', seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton1);
botonOpcion14.addEventListener('change', seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton2);
botonOpcion15.addEventListener('change', seleccionarDeseleccionarBoton2);

// Fragmento de código que controla el que se muestre el valor seleccionado en la barra deslizante dentro de la página
const barraDeslizante = document.getElementById('opcion1-rango');
const spanMostrarRangoSeleccionado = document.getElementById('mostrar-rango-seleccionado');
const contenedorSpan = document.querySelector('.p-mostrar-input-range');
let primeraValidacionBarDesliz = false;
let segundaValidacionBarDesliz = false;

barraDeslizante.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    contenedorSpan.classList.remove('oculto');
    spanMostrarRangoSeleccionado.classList.remove('oculto');

    // Primera validación de la barra deslizante
    primeraValidacionBarDesliz = true;
});

barraDeslizante.addEventListener('input', () => {
    spanMostrarRangoSeleccionado.textContent = barraDeslizante.value;

    // Condicional que verifica que se cumpla la tercera validación
    if (barraDeslizante.value != 0)
    {
        segundaValidacionBarDesliz = true;
        barraDeslizante.setCustomValidity("");
    }
});

// Oyente de eventos que valida que todas las opciones sean seleccionadas antes de mandar el formulario
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    let esValido1 = false;
    let esValido2 = false;
    let esValido3 = false;
    let esValido4 = false;
    
    // Fragmento de código valida que el input tipo rango haya sido presionado, que se levante el click y que cambie el valor de su estado inicial (validación de seleción del input tipo rango)
    const opcionRango = document.getElementById('opcion1-rango');
    
    if (primeraValidacionBarDesliz != true && segundaValidacionBarDesliz != true)
    {
        // Evita que se envíe el formulario al servidor
        esValido1 = false;
        opcionRango.setCustomValidity("Deslize la barra y seleccione un número.");
    }
    else
    {
        esValido1 = true;
        opcionRango.setCustomValidity("");
    }

    // Fragmento de código que valida que al menos una casilla de cada grupo sea seleccionada
    const casilla1 = document.getElementById('opcion9');
    const casilla2 = document.getElementById('opcion10');
    const casilla3 = document.getElementById('opcion11');
    const casilla4 = document.getElementById('opcion12');
    const casilla5 = document.getElementById('opcion13');
    const casilla6 = document.getElementById('opcion16');
    const casilla7 = document.getElementById('opcion17');
    const casilla8 = document.getElementById('opcion18');
    const casilla9 = document.getElementById('opcion19');
    const casilla10 = document.getElementById('opcion20');
    const casilla11 = document.getElementById('opcion26');
    const casilla12 = document.getElementById('opcion27');
    const casilla13 = document.getElementById('opcion28');
    const casilla14 = document.getElementById('opcion29');

    if (!casilla1.checked && !casilla2.checked && !casilla3.checked && !casilla4.checked && !casilla5.checked)
    {
        esValido2 = false;
        casilla1.setCustomValidity("Seleccione al menos una casilla.")
    }
    else if (casilla1.checked || casilla2.checked || casilla3.checked || casilla4.checked || casilla5.checked)
    {
        esValido2 = true;
        casilla1.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    
    if (!casilla6.checked && !casilla7.checked && !casilla8.checked && !casilla9.checked && !casilla10.checked)
    {
        esValido3 = false;
        casilla6.setCustomValidity("Seleccione al menos una casilla.")
    }
    else if (casilla6.checked || casilla7.checked || casilla8.checked || casilla9.checked || casilla10.checked)
    {
        esValido3 = true;
        casilla6.setCustomValidity("");
    }

    if (!casilla11.checked && !casilla12.checked && !casilla13.checked && !casilla14.checked)
    {
        esValido4 = false;
        casilla11.setCustomValidity("Seleccione al menos una casilla.")
    }
    else if (casilla11.checked || casilla12.checked || casilla13.checked || casilla14.checked)
    {
        esValido4 = true;
        casilla11.setCustomValidity("");
    }
        
    // Fragmento de código que controla la aparición del texto de agradecimiento y que todos los campos de formulario sean válidos para enviarlo
    const contenedorAgradecimiento = document.querySelector('.contenedor-agradecimiento');
    const textosAgradecimiento = document.querySelectorAll('.texto-agradecimiento');

    if (esValido1 && esValido2 && esValido3 && esValido4)
    {
        contenedorAgradecimiento.classList.remove('oculto');
        textosAgradecimiento.forEach(textoAgradecimiento => {textoAgradecimiento.classList.remove('oculto');});
    }
    else {e.preventDefault();}
});
:root
{
    --color-violeta: rgb(144, 0, 255);
}

/* Reinicia los estilos eliminando el margin y el padding */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.body
{
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.contenedor-principal
{
    margin: 0 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*.contenido-principal:last-child {margin-bottom: 30px}*/     /* En espera de corroborar su funcionamiento correcto */

.subcontenedor
{
    background-color: rgb(33,33,33);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: thin solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 13px;
    /*height: 300px;*/
}

.contenedor-imagen
{
    height: 100px;
}

.encabezado
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 35px 30px 30px 30px;
}
    
.linea-decoracion
{
    border-radius: 13px 13px 0 0;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.titulo-principal {margin: 0}

.titulo-pregunta {font-weight: bold}

.encabezado .parrafo
{
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]
{
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nombre-opcion {margin-left: 10px}

.textarea
{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 97%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    resize: vertical;
}

.textarea:focus {outline: none;}
.textarea-oculta {display: none}
.label-input {display: none}
.br {display: none}

/*----------------------------------------------Estilos para el input tipo range----------------------------------------*/
/* Estilo general del input (controla el aspecto de la barra horizontal) */
input[type=range] 
{
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Oculta el slider para que se pueda personalizar */
    width: 100%; /* Se requiere un ancho específico para Firefox */
    height: 10px;
    background: transparent; /* Se requiere un fondo trasnparente por que si no el fondo es blanco en Chrome */
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    border-radius: 15px;
}

/* Resetea el estilo por defecto */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {-webkit-appearance: none;}

/* Elimina el borde azul característicos */
input[type=range]:focus {outline: none;}
  
input[type=range]::-ms-track
{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Oculta el slider para que se puedan agregar estilos personalizados */
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
  
/* Estilo del thumb (controla el estilo de la parte que se desliza) */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.p-mostrar-input-range
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.span-mostrar-rango
{
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.select
{
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    appearance: none;
}

/* Clase que sirve para ocultar etiquetas */
.oculto {display: none}

.contenedor-boton-enviar
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn-enviar
{
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 77px;
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-enviar:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px var(--color-violeta);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn-enviar:not(:hover)
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.contenedor-agradecimiento
{
    margin-bottom: 110px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.contenedor-agradecimiento h1, .contenedor-agradecimiento h3 {text-align: center}

.contenedor-agradecimiento h1
{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contenedor-agradecimiento h3 {font-size: 30px}
<body class="body">
        <!--Contenedor principal-->
        <form id="formulario" class="contenedor-principal" method="post" onsubmit="validarFormulario(e)">
            <div class="subcontenedor contenedor-imagen">
                Aqui va una imagen
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor encabezado">
                <div class="linea-decoracion"></div>
                <h1 class="titulo-principal">Encuesta de calidad del servicio</h1>
                <p class="parrafo">
                    Ayúdenos a mejorar nuestro servicio contandonos su experiencia navegando en la página, comprando nuestros productos o servicios.
                    A continuación, responda honestamente como fue su recorido durante la página.<br>
                    Su información es muy valiosa para nosotros.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta1">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">1.  ¿De 1 al 10 que probabilidad hay que recomiendes nuestro sitio web a familiares o amigos?</label><br><br>
                <input type="range" id="opcion1-rango" name="opcion1-rango" class="opcion-rango" min="1" max="10" value="0">
                <p class="p-mostrar-input-range oculto"><span id="mostrar-rango-seleccionado" class="span-mostrar-rango oculto"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta2">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">2.  ¿Del 1 al 5 que tan animgable con el usuario consideras la página?</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion2" name="opciones2" class="opciones" value="1" required><label for="opcion2" class="nombre-opcion">1</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion3" name="opciones2" class="opciones" value="2"><label for="opcion3" class="nombre-opcion">2</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion4" name="opciones2" class="opciones" value="3"><label for="opcion4" class="nombre-opcion">3</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion5" name="opciones2" class="opciones" value="4"><label for="opcion5" class="nombre-opcion">4</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion6" name="opciones2" class="opciones" value="5"><label for="opcion6" class="nombre-opcion">5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta3">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">3.  ¿Su experiencia dentro de la página fue agradable?</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion7" name="opciones3" class="opciones" value="Si" required><label for="opcion7" class="nombre-opcion">Si</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion8" name="opciones3" class="opciones" value="No"><label for="opcion8" class="nombre-opcion">No</label>
                <br class="br"><br class="br">
                <label for="opcion8-input" class="label-input label8-input">¿Por que?</label>
                <textarea name="opcion8-input" id="opcion8-input" class="textarea textarea-oculta" maxlength="300" placeholder="Cuéntanos tu inconformidad..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta4">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">4.  ¿Qué elementos considera que le hacen falta al sitio web?</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion9" name="casillas1" class="opciones" value="Mayor responsividad"><label for="opcion9" class="nombre-opcion">Mayor responsividad</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion10" name="casillas1" class="opciones" value="Más colores"><label for="opcion10" class="nombre-opcion">Más colores</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion11" name="casillas1" class="opciones" value="Más animaciones"><label for="opcion11" class="nombre-opcion">Más animaciones</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion12" name="casillas1" class="opciones" value="Más contenido"><label for="opcion12" class="nombre-opcion">Más contenido</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion13" name="casillas1" class="opciones" value="Mejor descripción en los productos"><label for="opcion13" class="nombre-opcion">Mejor descripción en los productos</label>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta5">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">5.  ¿Considera que los precios son justos?</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion14" name="opciones5" class="opciones" value="Si" required><label for="opcion14" class="nombre-opcion">Si</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion15" name="opciones5" class="opciones" value="No"><label for="opcion15" class="nombre-opcion">No</label><br class="br"><br class="br">
                <label for="opcion15-input" class="label-input label15-input">¿Por que?</label>
                <textarea name="opcion15-input" id="opcion15-input" class="textarea textarea-oculta" maxlength="300" placeholder="Cuéntanos por que crees que los precios no son justos..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta6">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">6.  De acuerdo a su criterio, ¿cómo considera la inclusión de la promoción de los libros al sitio?</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion16" name="casillas2" class="opciones" value="Interesante"><label for="opcion14" class="nombre-opcion">Interesante</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion17" name="casillas2" class="opciones" value="Innovadora"><label for="opcion15" class="nombre-opcion">Innovadora</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion18" name="casillas2" class="opciones" value="Inusual"><label for="opcion16" class="nombre-opcion">Inusual</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion19" name="casillas2" class="opciones" value="Inadecuada"><label for="opcion17" class="nombre-opcion">Inadecuada</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion20" name="casillas2" class="opciones" value="Perfecta"><label for="opcion18" class="nombre-opcion">Perfecta</label>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta7">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">7.  ¿Qué opina de nuestras opciones de servicios?</label><br><br>
                <select name="seleccion-opciones" id="seleccion-opciones" class="select" required>
                    <option value="" class="option" selected disabled>Seleccione una opción</option>
                    <option value="Son adecuadas a la página" class="option">Son adecuadas a la página</option>
                    <option value="Son variadas" class="option">Son variadas</option>
                    <option value="Son poco variadas" class="option">Son poco variadas</option>
                    <option value="Están bien pero le hacen falta más opciones" class="option">Están bien pero le hacen falta más opciones</option>
                    <option value="Están perfectas" class="option">Están perfectas</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta8">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">8.  Si ha probado nuestras apliaciones, ¿sobre qué temas le gustaría que creemos nuevas aplicaciones?</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion21" name="casillas3" class="opciones" value="Matemáticas y cálculo"><label for="opcion24" class="nombre-opcion">Matemáticas y cálculo</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion22" name="casillas3" class="opciones" value="Tiendas"><label for="opcion25" class="nombre-opcion">Tiendas</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion22" name="casillas3" class="opciones" value="Videojuegos"><label for="opcion26" class="nombre-opcion">Videojuegos</label><br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="opcion23" name="casillas3" class="opciones" value="Miscelaneo"><label for="opcion27" class="nombre-opcion">Miscelaneo</label>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta9">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">9.  ¿Encontró lo que buscaba dentro de la página?</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion24" name="opciones9" class="opciones" value="Si" required><label for="opcion28" class="nombre-opcion" required>Si</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion25" name="opciones9" class="opciones" value="No" ><label for="opcion29" class="nombre-opcion">No</label><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="opcion26" name="opciones9" class="opciones" value="Si y no"><label for="opcion30" class="nombre-opcion">Si y no</label>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontenedor pregunta10">
                <label class="titulo-pregunta">10.  Para concluir, ¿qué aspectos considera que pueden mejorar la estética de la página y la calidad de nuestro servicio o productos?</label><br><br>
                <textarea name="opcion27-input" id="opcion27" class="textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Cuéntanos tu opinión..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor-boton-enviar">
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" title="Enviar el formulario" class="btn-enviar">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor-agradecimiento oculto">
                <h1 class="texto-agradecimiento oculto">¡Muchas gracias!</h1>
                <h3 class="texto-agradecimiento oculto">Te agradecemos grandemente por responder nuestra encuesta. Que tengas un lindo día</h3>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!--?php
            include("registro-formulario-encuesta.php");
        ?-->

        <script src="../js/script-formulario-encuesta.js"></script>
    </body>




¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Has publicado una gran cantidad de código. Funciona mejor cuando preparas un [mcve] con el que quien quiera responderte pueda reproducir el problema (completo), contenga solo el código esencial para reproducirlo (mínimo) y así tenga un punto de partida para una posible respuesta. Eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.
